# How to get data in array

Tags: python, arrays

I am a beginner to python and trying to implement a leaderboard system. I have the below array.

`points = [(userid1, 500),(userid2,600),(userid3,100)]`

How do I use python to get userid3's points.

Thanks

Comment: `dict(points)[userid1]`

Comment: Please repeat the intro tour, especially [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).  This is basic Python syntax, something you look up in any tutorial on lists, tuples, etc.  Stack Overflow is not intended as a research or tutorial resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python, you access the i*th* element of a list with the syntax `list[i-1]` (because list indexes start at 0).

Therefore, `userid3_info = points[2]` will give the variable `userid3_info` the value `(userid3,100)`.

You do the same thing to access the j*th* element of a tuple.
So `userid3_points = userid3_info[1]` will give `userid3_points` the value `100`

Answer (score 0):

To get elements of the differents collections of python always use []. Points is a list of tuples, both are collections of data. So to access "userid3" point you should do `points[2][1]`. Inside the brackets you specify the index of the element, in this case "userid3" is in the position 2 of the list (counting from 0) and the points of it is in position 1.

Comment: I think, you should add some details to your  answer and include information how to access to second element of tuple by value of first element, not just static index.

Answer (score 0):

You refer to an array element by referring to the index number.

you can use something like this `points[2]` it will access tuple. you can get user userid3 point by `points[2][1]`

refer [This Post](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_arrays.asp)